# String after Escaped Characters in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regular expressions in Python. I'm trying to pull out all the data between 2 variables, it starts with {"justin_h and ends with "} special characters included, however I'm having trouble with the regex syntax.

I've been using:

```
[{]["][justin_h...["][}]
```

And it returns no results. I know for a fact it's in there, and the [{]["] returns results, but it's when I start the string it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: To match `{` or any other special character you can use `\{`. Also, make sure you are using raw strings, that is `r'blabla'` instead of `'blabla'`. 

Would be nice if you provide an exact piece of your matched text, and expected result.

Comment: I've read it works using [ ] as well, but adapting the regex with \ still returns no results.

Comment: @user5061: You can also use `[{]` in many languages' regex implementations. @ajh: The `...` will match exactly 3 characters - is that what you want? To match any sequence of characters you'd want `.*` instead.

Comment: You are right, what i meant is that it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capturing groups or lookarounds.

```
r'\{"justin_h(.*?)"}'
```

Grab the string you want from group index 1. It won't work, if the part you want to grab contain newline character. For that case, you need to use `(?s)` DOTALL flag.

```
r'(?s)\{"justin_h(.*?)"}'
```

Example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\{"justin_h(.*?)"}', 'foo{"justin_hfoobar"}barfoo')
['foobar']
```

Comment: Do I need to escape the last "} at the end of the regex?

Comment: Hmmm it still doesn't seem to return any results :/, does this work in Python?

Comment: Apologies, a coding error my end, it does work thanks :). However, I'd like it to include the searched results, for me it returns all the data between those two variable non inclusive, how do I adapt it to include the searched data also in my result?

Comment: then remove the capturing group from the regex like `r'\{"justin_h.*?"}`